# Access to Power consumption Details on Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, power-management

Currently I'm searching for a way to access the Data about the power consumption of Devices that run Mac OS X. I'm mostly interested in the Power Usage in Watts. 
The `IOPowerSources.h` of `IOKit` provides lots of Information, but it's only for Devices powered by Batteries or UPS-Devices. Is there a way to access the Power Usage of a Mac that's not powered by Batteries?

Thank you!

Comment: I've found that a 'Kill-a-watt' device is excellent for measuring the power consumption of all the electrical components in my home/office, because, sadly, unless there's a sensor explicitly measuring it, all you'll be able to calculate is some of the components (e.g. CPU draw). (as an aside, some IPMI enabled systems have power supply sensors that measure the power draw - I've one that shows 164W & 184W for the two power supplies)